# How to remove pacemaker, corosync and pcs thoroughly on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7, cluster, pacemaker, corosync, remove

Using two nodes:

- node1: 192.168.0.1
- node2: 192.168.0.2

Installed HA tools on both servers:

```
yum install pacemaker pcs
```

(It will include install corosync)

On both servers:

```
passwd hacluster
```

Set same password for cluster.

On both servers:

```
systemctl enable pcsd.service
systemctl start pcsd.service
```

Authenticating the cluster nodes:

```
node1# pcs cluster auth 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
```

All of them successful authenticated.

Generating the corosync configuration:

```
node1# pcs cluster setup --name mycluster 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
```

Starting the cluster:

```
node1# pcs cluster start --all
```

Success.

Confirm status:

```
pcs status corosync

Output
Membership information
----------------------
    Nodeid      Votes Name
         2          1 192.168.0.2
         1          1 192.168.0.1 (local)
```

Get more information about the current status of the cluster:

```
pcs cluster status

Output
Cluster Status:
 ...
 Stack: corosync
 ...
 2 nodes and 0 resources configured
 Online: [ node1 node2 ]

PCSD Status:
  node1 (192.168.0.1): Online
  node2 (192.168.0.2): Online
```

Enable the corosync and pacemaker services on both servers:

```
systemctl enable corosync.service
systemctl enable pacemaker.service
```

Disabling STONITH

```
node1# pcs property set stonith-enabled=false
```

After created a float IP and added it to pcs resource, test failover.

On node1:

```
reboot
```

Then got trouble. After it rebooted, run `pcs cluster status` again, it showed:

```
  Cluster Status:
   Stack: corosync
   Current DC: centos7lb1 (version 1.1.15-11.el7_3.5-e174ec8) - partition WITHOUT quorum
   Last updated: Sun Jul 23 23:47:53 2017         Last change: Fri Jul 21 05:56:32 2017 by hacluster via crmd on node1
   1 node and 0 resources configured

  PCSD Status:
    node1 (192.168.0.1): Online
    *Unknown* (192.168.0.2): Online
```

Run `pcs status` on node1:

```
    Cluster name: mycluster
    WARNING: corosync and pacemaker node names do not match (IPs used in setup?)
    Stack: corosync
    Current DC: node1 (version 1.1.15-11.el7_3.5-e174ec8) - partition WITHOUT quorum
    Last updated: Sun Jul 23 23:58:22 2017          Last change: Fri Jul 21 05:56:32 2017 by hacluster via crmd on node1

    1 node and 0 resources configured

    Online: [ node1 ]

    No resources


    Daemon Status:
      corosync: active/disabled
      pacemaker: active/disabled
      pcsd: active/enabled
```

Can't find `node2` in the cluster. At the same time check the status on node2, got only one node(`node2`), too. The same as node1, can't find another node in the cluster.

---

I tried to remove pacemaker, corosync and pcs and redo it again. But after do that like:

```
yum remove pacemaker pcs
```

Then authenticate them:

```
pcs cluster auth node1 node2
```

Showed they `Already authorized`.

At this time, how to join the two nodes into the cluster rightly again? I want to remove them clearly, then how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was the firewall.

Because Corosync uses UDP transport on ports 5404 and 5405, I added:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp -m multiport --dports 5404,5405 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp -m multiport --sports 5404,5405 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

and stop/start all cluster:

```
pcs cluster stop --all
pcs cluster start --all
```

Also ran:

```
service corosync restart
```

The cluster works. All the nodes can been seen and all of them online.

Comment: Resource: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/admin_cm_ha_failover.html